# Tabs in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

What i mean in my question is the following :

[image: ActionBar Tabs](https://s2.postimg.org/qy6gdl761/Untitled.png]

'Android new dialer app' :

[image]
How can i add these tabs to my ActionBar? And how do i style them? 
*Please don't suggest using libraries*

Comment: I think Android have not provided any thing for that, you have to look for custom library

Comment: @pokerface do you know any?

Comment: never saw any library doing this task, let me search if I can find any

Comment: android provides PagerTitleStrip, which does what you want but the problem is that tabs will not be in action bar, it will be below action bar

Comment: @pokerface that wont be helpful in my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use PagerTitleStrip Provided by android as suggested in comments but to solve the problem try to:
add that to your manifest file

```
android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

and disable the action bar icon and title with `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);` and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) is a link to get you start from android developers: